# Given gradle 2.13 and the eclipse plugin, how do I add generated sources to the classpath?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

Documentation and examples leave something to be desired (i.e. they are out of date).

The newest DSL doesn't seem to allow adding generated source. In a nutshell, I have an XJC task that generates some Java from XML. Now I'm an IntelliJ guy, so I don't know if I'm supposed to add the *.class files or the *.java files to the Eclipse classpath but in IntelliJ, its Java files. Class files end up in `build/classes` while the Java ends up under `generated-src`.

The DSL seems to want a configuration. IDK how to create a configuration AFTER the *.class files have been generated.

Comment: are you using buildship?

Comment: Yes. We are using the buildship plugin.